# fallback on XHR fail, outside of the XHR function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am doing an XMLHttpRequest and I would like to fallback on doing something else (reading a local file) if it fails, but I want to do it outside of the XHR function (getDBfileXHR) itself.

I am using Jquery too.

How is that possible, given the fact that it doesn't seem to work with `.done()` and `.fail()`, maybe with a deferred variable or something else ?

```
getDBfileXHR( encode_utf8("http://john:hispasswd@mysite.com/DBfile.jsonp") );
//here I want to do something else if getDBfileXHR fails like this :
fallbackToLocalDBfile();


function getDBfileXHR(url) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", url, true); //3rd parameter is sync/async
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {      //Call a function when the state changes.
       if (request.readyState == 4) {
          if (request.status == 200 || request.status == 0) {
             console.log('we get a response from XHR');
             var jsonText = request.responseText.replace("callback(", "");
             jsonText = jsonText.replace(");", "");
             storeJsonInProdata(JSON.parse(jsonText));
             dbReadyDeferred.resolve(); 
          } else {
            console.log('error : request.status = '+request.status);
          }
       }
    }
    console.log("Sending XMLHttpRequest...");
    request.send();
}

function fallbackToLocalDBfile(){
    $.get('proDB.jsonp').done(function(data){
        console.log(data);
        //storeJsonInProdata(data);
        //dbReadyDeferred.resolve();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mmm something like this maybe :

```
   var d=$.Deferred()

    function getDBfileXHR(url) {
     ....
           if (request.readyState == 4) {
            ...
                 d.resolve(_MyData); 
              } else {
                console.log('error : request.status = '+request.status);
                d.reject(_myError);

              }
           }
        }
        console.log("Sending XMLHttpRequest...");
        request.send();
    }

    d.done(function (a){...}).fail(function (b){});
```